# How to use form-inline bootstrap 3?

Tags: html, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap, razor

I have a view in HTML and Razor and I am trying to build a form to look like the following:
[image: mockup image]

However, the best I can achieve is the following:

[image: result image]

As you can see the labels are not inlined. 
To achieve this I have read about the `form-inline` class in Bootstrap 3 (http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-forms) but no matter how I use form-inline I cannot get the labels into the right place without making the whole layout a mess.

This is my current code (without form-inline):

```
 <fieldset class="group-border">
                    <legend class="group-border">Info</legend>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-4">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                @Html.LabelFor(doc => doc.NumDoc, new { @class = "control-label" })
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(doc => doc.NumDoc, new { @class = "form-control input-sm", placeholder = "Nº Documento", disabled = "disabled" })
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                @Html.LabelFor(doc => doc.ProcessNum, new { @class = "control-label" })
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(doc => doc.ProcessNum, new { @class = "form-control input-sm", placeholder = "Nº Processo", disabled = "disabled" })
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                @Html.LabelFor(doc => doc.State, new { @class = "control-label" })
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(doc => doc.State, new { @class = "form-control input-sm", placeholder = "Estado", disabled = "disabled" })
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                @Html.LabelFor(doc => doc.Name, new { @class = "control-label" })
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(doc => doc.Name, new { @class = "form-control input-sm", placeholder = "Nome Documento", disabled = "disabled" })
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            @Html.LabelFor(doc => doc.IsArchived, new { @class = "control-label" })
                            @Html.CheckBoxFor(doc => doc.IsArchived, new { @class = "input-sm", disabled = "disabled" })
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                @Html.LabelFor(doc => doc.Description, new { @class = "control-label" })
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(doc => doc.Description, new { @class = "form-control input-sm", placeholder = "Descrição", disabled = "disabled" })
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                @Html.LabelFor(doc => doc.Date, new { @class = "control-label" })
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(doc => doc.Date, new { @class = "form-control input-sm", placeholder = "dd/MM/yyyy", disabled = "disabled" })
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </fieldset>
```

Bellow is a code snippet in HTML CSS and Javascript, trying to replicate what I have.

```css
<style> legend.group-border {
  width: inherit;
  /* Or auto */
  padding: 0 10px;
  /* To give a bit of padding on the left and right */
  border-bottom: none;
}
fieldset.group-border {
  border: 1px groove #ddd !important;
  padding: 0 1.4em 1.4em 1.4em !important;
  margin: 0 0 1.5em 0 !important;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px #000;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px #000;
}
</style>
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<fieldset class="group-border">
  <legend class="group-border">Info</legend>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="NumDoc">Nº Documento</label>
        <input class="form-control input-sm" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Nº Documento must be a number." data-val-required="O campo Nº Documento é necessário." disabled="disabled" id="NumDoc" name="NumDoc" placeholder="Nº Documento" type="text"
        value="21354">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="ProcessNum">Nº Processo</label>
        <input class="form-control input-sm" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Nº Processo  must be a number." data-val-required="O campo Nº Processo  é necessário." disabled="disabled" id="ProcessNum" name="ProcessNum" placeholder="Nº Processo" type="text"
        value="54463">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="State">Estado</label>
        <input class="form-control input-sm" disabled="disabled" id="State" name="State" placeholder="Estado" type="text" value="Em Inbox">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="Name">Nome</label>
        <input class="form-control input-sm" disabled="disabled" id="Name" name="Name" placeholder="Nome Documento" type="text" value="A134-MULTAS">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <label class="control-label" for="IsArchived">Arquivado?</label>
      <input checked="checked" class="input-sm" data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo Arquivado? é necessário." disabled="disabled" id="IsArchived" name="IsArchived" type="checkbox" value="true">
      <input name="IsArchived" type="hidden" value="false">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="Description">Descrição</label>
        <input class="form-control input-sm" disabled="disabled" id="Description" name="Description" placeholder="Descrição" type="text" value="Fast and Furious">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="Date">Data Documento</label>
        <input class="form-control input-sm" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field Data Documento must be a date." data-val-required="O campo Data Documento é necessário." disabled="disabled" id="Date" name="Date" placeholder="dd/MM/yyyy" type="text" value="25/08/2015 15:03:26">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</fieldset>
```

As you can see, I have a row, divided into 3 columns (each one occupying a width of 4 units) and inside I have my forms using Razor.

How would one modify my current HTML code to achieve the result in the mockup?

Comment: You used the `<form class="form group">`. Twitter-Bootstrap 3 provides some documentation about _inline form_ that you can access here : http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline.

Comment: I already know of `form-inline`, but it doesn't seem to work in my layout.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the code snippet, I just changed the `form-group` class to the `form-inline`, changed the number of columns and their width, and just to make it work add the `container`, `row` and `col-md-12` divs, also I tried to align vertically the `checkbox` to look more like your first mockup image

```css
<style> legend.group-border {
  width: inherit;
  /* Or auto */
  padding: 0 10px;
  /* To give a bit of padding on the left and right */
  border-bottom: none;
}
fieldset.group-border {
  border: 1px groove #ddd !important;
  padding: 0 1.4em 1.4em 1.4em !important;
  margin: 0 0 1.5em 0 !important;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px #000;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px #000;
}
</style>
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <fieldset class="group-border">
                        <legend class="group-border">Info</legend>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-4">
                                <div class="form-inline">
                                    <label class="control-label" for="NumDoc">Nº Documento</label>
                                    <input class="form-control input-sm" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Nº Documento must be a number." data-val-required="O campo Nº Documento é necessário." disabled="disabled" id="NumDoc" name="NumDoc" placeholder="Nº Documento" value="21354" type="text">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-4">
                                <div class="form-inline">
                                    <label class="control-label" for="ProcessNum">Nº Processo</label>
                                    <input class="form-control input-sm" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Nº Processo  must be a number." data-val-required="O campo Nº Processo  é necessário." disabled="disabled" id="ProcessNum" name="ProcessNum" placeholder="Nº Processo" value="54463" type="text">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-4">
                                <div class="form-inline">
                                    <label class="control-label" for="State">Estado</label>
                                    <input class="form-control input-sm" disabled="disabled" id="State" name="State" placeholder="Estado" value="Em Inbox" type="text">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <br>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-1">
                                <label class="control-label" for="Name">Nome</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-7">
                                <input class="form-control input-sm" disabled="disabled" id="Name" name="Name" placeholder="Nome Documento" value="A134-MULTAS" type="text">
                            </div>
                            <div style="float: left;" class="col-lg-4 text-left">
                                <input style="float: left;" checked="checked" class="input-sm" data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo Arquivado? é necessário." disabled="disabled" id="IsArchived" name="IsArchived" value="true" type="checkbox">
                                <label style="margin-top: 10px; margin-left: 9px;" class="control-label" for="IsArchived">Arquivado?</label>
                                <input name="IsArchived" value="false" type="hidden">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <br>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-1">
                                <label class="control-label" for="Description">Descrição</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-7">
                                <input class="form-control input-sm" disabled="disabled" id="Description" name="Description" placeholder="Descrição" value="Fast and Furious" type="text">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-4">
                                <div class="form-inline">
                                    <label class="control-label" for="Date">Data Documento</label>
                                    <input class="form-control input-sm" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field Data Documento must be a date." data-val-required="O campo Data Documento é necessário." disabled="disabled" id="Date" name="Date" placeholder="dd/MM/yyyy" value="25/08/2015 15:03:26" type="text">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

After checking for alternatives, we ended up using `from-horizontal`. According to bootstrap documentation, this solution should be more viable if you want to use columns (in this case `col-lg-X`) because adding this class will make the inner children behave like they were inside a `row` object, which is what one needs to properly align one form.

The documentation can be seen here:

- http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal

I also added a few other styles to the CSS.

This solution works perfectly for our needs and it does avoid messing with margins and setting values in pixels like in the previous solution. For all purposes, if you want a form in a simple grid, this is the way to go **imo**.

However, given the effort and the objectiveness of Enrique Zavaleta, I have decided to choose his answer over this one. Keep it going!

Bellow is my code snippet. Hope you all enjoy!

```css
    legend {
      margin-bottom: 0px;
    }
    legend.group-border {
      width: inherit;
      /* Or auto */
      padding: 0 10px;
      /* To give a bit of padding on the left and right */
      border-bottom: none;
    }
    fieldset.group-border {
      border: 1px groove #ddd !important;
      padding: 0 1.4em 1.4em 1.4em !important;
      margin: 0 0 1.5em 0 !important;
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px #000;
      box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px #000;
    }
    .small input {
      height: 22px;
      padding: 2px 5px;
      font-size: 12px;
      line-height: 1.5;
      border-radius: 3px;
    }
    /*left align all labels*/
    .form-horizontal .control-label {
      text-align: left !important;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<fieldset class="group-border">
  <legend class="group-border">Info</legend>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 form-horizontal">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-lg-6" for="NumDoc">Nº Documento</label>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <input class="form-control input-sm" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Nº Documento must be a number." data-val-required="O campo Nº Documento é necessário." disabled="disabled" id="NumDoc" name="NumDoc" placeholder="Nº Documento" type="text"
          value="21354">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-4 form-horizontal">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-lg-5" for="ProcessNum">Nº Processo</label>
        <div class="col-lg-7">
          <input class="form-control input-sm" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Nº Processo  must be a number." data-val-required="O campo Nº Processo  é necessário." disabled="disabled" id="ProcessNum" name="ProcessNum" placeholder="Nº Processo" type="text"
          value="54463">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-4 form-horizontal">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-lg-3" for="State">Estado</label>
        <div class="col-lg-9">
          <input class="form-control input-sm" disabled="disabled" id="State" name="State" placeholder="Estado" type="text" value="Em Inbox">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-8 form-horizontal">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-lg-2" for="Name">Nome</label>
        <div class="col-lg-10">
          <input class="form-control input-sm" disabled="disabled" id="Name" name="Name" placeholder="Nome Documento" type="text" value="A134-MULTAS">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 form-horizontal">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-lg-5" for="IsArchived">Arquivado?</label>
        <div class="col-lg-7">
          <input checked="checked" class="input-sm" data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo Arquivado? é necessário." disabled="disabled" id="IsArchived" name="IsArchived" type="checkbox" value="true">
          <input name="IsArchived" type="hidden" value="false">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-8 form-horizontal">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-lg-2" for="Description">Descrição</label>
        <div class="col-lg-10">
          <input class="form-control input-sm" disabled="disabled" id="Description" name="Description" placeholder="Descrição" type="text" value="Fast and Furious">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 form-horizontal">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-lg-2" for="Date">Data</label>
        <div class="col-lg-8">
          <input class="form-control input-sm" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field Data must be a date." data-val-required="O campo Data é necessário." disabled="disabled" id="Date" name="Date" placeholder="dd/MM/yyyy" type="text" value="26/08/2015 10:48:43">
        </div>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</fieldset>
```